# IOS Localizations Global

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization

Its been a couple of years since I worked on IOS, but now that I've created one with the latest Xcode 5.1 I see that there is a "Global" localization. I've always assumed that if the user has a localization that it is not supported by the app, that it will revert to the Localization native development region property in the info.plist. 
Has this changed ? and what does the global do exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Global localization? Do you mean perhaps "Base localization"?

The question is really too broad to answer in the SO format. In short, however: base localization (coupled with auto layout) allows you to you use your reference language (usually your native language) in your storyboards and xibs. When you add a localization to your app, Xcode generates a strings file for all the text that is contained in each UI file.

Good starting point to read up on the new localization guidelines: [Apple Developer Internationalization guide](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)